# Installation failed: Destination folder already exists

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, web-hosting

Hi I was working on Wordpress and notification popped up regarding Woocomerce update, I click on it but i dont know how it failed and then woocomerce isnt showing on my plugins , nor on side bar of my wp admin panel. On my site the error coming up is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_product()
in
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/woo-variation-swatches.php:314 Stack trace: #0
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): Woo_Variation_Swatches->enqueue_scripts('') #1
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-includes/script-loader.php(2231): do_action('wp_enqueue_scri...') #4
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): wp_enqueue_scripts('') #5
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #6
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #7
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-includes/general-template.php(2614): do_action('wp_head') #8 /home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-conten in
/home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/woo-variation-swatches.php on line 314
```

and i hosted this site from Hosterpk. kindly help.

Comment: Did you write any custom function in theme file? its coming from the woo-variation-swatches plugin. Also, is woocommerce main plugin is activated?

Comment: This plugin is the problem - woo-variation-swatches

Answer (score 0):

You can connect with your wordpress site using FTP. then move to /home/homesnoo/clifsauce.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/ and rename woo-variation-swatches to woo-variation-swatches-delete and try to run update once again. if FTP allows you to rename. your update will work.